# Can i use file locking in this scenario?

Tags: perl, filelock

Please i have a conceptual question. I have two processes that outputs a file with the same name in the same directory and then execute/read that file in a perl script. These two processes can be run concurrently and i am afraid there is a chance the file can be over written by the other process hence one of the process executing an incorrect source file. essentially the line is like this : (the two lines are common to both processes)

```perl
$cmd = `my_script.pl`;  ## This generates runx file
$cmd = `source runx | grep - i "Error";`
```

NOTE: I don't have control over the name of the file and i must run both processes in the same

Can i use an exclusive file lock right after the first command to prevent collusion?

Answer (score 2):

The file you lock doesn't have to be the file you want to protect.

```perl
use Fcntl qw( LOCK_EX );

my $output;
{
   my $script_qfn = 'my_script.pl';
   my $lock_qfn  = $script_qfn . '.lock';

   open(my $fh, '>', $lock_qfn)
      or die("Can't create lock file \"$lock_qfn\": $!\n");

   flock($fh, LOCK_EX)
      or die("Can't lock \"$lock_qfn\": $!\n");

   system { $script_qfn } $script_qfn;
   $output = `source runx | grep -i Error`;
}
```

But why not have `my_script.pl` send its output to STDOUT? Then there would be no need to lock. You could simply use the following:

```perl
my $output = `my_script.pl | sh | grep -i Error`;
```

---

There are three ways of calling `system`:

- `system($shell_command)`.
- `system($prog, @args)`. Has to have at least one arg.
- `system({ $prog } $arg0, @args)`. 0+ args.

In this case, we didn't have shell command, and we didn't have any args, so we had to use the third approach (or build a shell command, say, using String::ShellQuote's `shell_quote`). To use `system($script_qfn)` would have introduced a [code injection bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

Comment: May i as why you have the code body in { } ? Is that just for clarity?
I can also try your other suggestion.

Comment: Answer added to bottom of post. `system($script_qfn)` would have introduced a [code injection bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really awesome to know that i can just have the lock on the perl script in the two processes calling the script! I like that idea!